# Make a slider/select fetching data in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I've got two tables: `Subjects` and `Careers` :

- "`Subjects`" includes (`id`, **`careers_id` (is the foreign key to the column "`id`" of the table Careers)** `subject`, `description`, `hours`)
- "`Careers`" includes (`id`,`name`,`description`)

I put a button which allows me to add a new subject. So when I click on it another page open. I need to add a slider/select which shows me the careers available in the table career. Take a look,I need something like this :

[image: select]

Here is my code to add a new subject (it works,but i dont know how to make the slider/select which fetch data from the table careers :/)

```
<?php include('connect.php'); 
    $error="";

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $carreras_id=$_POST['txtcarreras_id'];
        $subject=$_POST['txtsubject'];
        $descripcion=$_POST['txtdescripcion'];
        $carga_horaria=$_POST['txtcarga_horaria'];


        if($_POST['txtid']=="0")
        {

            $a_sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subjects VALUES('','$carreras_id','$subject','$descripcion','$carga_horaria')");
            if($a_sql)
            {

                header("location:index.php");

            }


        }else{

            echo "Actualizar";
        }

    }
?>

<h2 align="center">ADD NEW SUBJECT</h2>
<form method="Post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Career:</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='txtcarreras_id' />
                <input type="hidden" name="txtid" value="0" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='txtsubject' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='txtdescripcion' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hours:</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='txtcarga_horaria' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='submit' value=save name='btnsave' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I don't know what to do?

Hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build your `<option>`s you would do something like this ->

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Careers");
$options = "";
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $options .= "<option value='".$result['id']."'>".$result['name']."</option>";
}
```

(**Note** - you should update from `mysql_` to `MySQLi` or `PDO` - [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) )

Then you would change your `<input>` to a `<select>` with your `$options` ->

```
<tr>    
    <td>Career:</td>
    <td><select name='txtcarreras_id'><?php echo $options; ?></select><input type="hidden" name="txtid" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Then you need to look at the code where the `$options` value is created. some simple debugging - (1) add `mysql_error()` -> `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Careers") or die( mysql_error() );`. (2) check if you have any rows retuned -> `if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) { while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ... } else {  $options .= "<option value='0'>No Careers</option>"; }`. (3) ...

Comment: You are awesome pal!, can i ask you something about another topic?